# Use template with base class as parameter

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I would like to define a template class with specialization of some methods for different types.

```
template <typename T>
class Handler {
public:
    void method1() { method2(); }
protected:
    void method2();
}
```

Then in the implementation file:

```
template <> Handler<int>::method2() { doSomething(); }
template <> Handler<float>::method2() { doSomethingElse(); }
template <> Handler<ClassB>::method2() { doSomethingDifferent(); }
```

So far, everything works ok.

Now I would like to define some new classes derived from ClassB, and use the template specialization on objects of these classes. Of course it compiles but does not link, because the specialization for each subclass is missing.

Is there a way to use the template for these, for example using SFINAE?

Comment: You could include your template code in your header file - thats probably not what you are looking for though

Comment: Template specialization is conceptually different from inheritance. You can't have a template with a member function that isn't defined and expect it to work like this. Are you maybe looking for [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)? If not, please be more clear about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often find overloading on a type tag a good alterantive to specialization:

```
namespace {

template<class T> struct Type { using type = T; }; // Or boost::type<T>
template<class T> struct TypeTag { using type = Type<T>; };

struct ClassB {};

template <typename T>
class Handler {
public:
    void method1() {
        method2(typename TypeTag<T>::type{}); // Call an overloaded function.
    }
protected:
    void method2(Type<int>) { std::printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
    void method2(Type<float>)  { std::printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
    void method2(Type<ClassB>)  { std::printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
};

// Somewhere else.
struct ClassC : ClassB {};
template<> struct TypeTag<ClassC> { using type = Type<ClassB>; };

} // namespace

int main(int ac, char**) {
    Handler<ClassB> b;
    b.method1();

    Handler<ClassC> c;
    c.method1();
}
```

Outputs:

```
void {anonymous}::Handler<T>::method2({anonymous}::Type<{anonymous}::ClassB>) [with T = {anonymous}::ClassB]
void {anonymous}::Handler<T>::method2({anonymous}::Type<{anonymous}::ClassB>) [with T = {anonymous}::ClassC]
```

Comment: I'm going to try it out.This looks like the classic solution using an additional level of indirection.

Comment: @GB Yes, your observation is spot on. Another way to look at it, is that you map all types to several specific categories. `TypeTag<T>` maps type `T` to category `TypeTag<T>::type`. Specializing `TypeTag<T>` allows to define a category for any type.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
template <class T,class=void>
class Handler
```

then use SFINAE to create a specialization:

```
template <class T>
class Handler<T,std::enable_if_t<test>>
```

Now, have that specialization either include its implementation in its body, or inherit from an implementation type (non-template) and implement that in the impl file.

For your puroposes, the test might be is base of.

Your int impl now needs a `,void` parameter added.

You can also use a traits class to do conditional mapping.